# Where is the called party indicated?

Tags: sip

Where is the caller being called in the message?
The provider says that it should be specified after INVITE (044123456@).
The developer of our PBX insists that the called subscriber should be specified only in the TO field (431234567@).
Who is right?

```
09:46:21:643    4036  RECV     -- UDP 963 Bytes FROM *.*.*.*:5060 IFACE *.*.*.*:5060
INVITE sip:044123456@*.*.*.*:5060;user=phone SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP *.*.*.*:5060;branch=z9hG4bKvspa8h207ot1h01df1g1.1
Call-ID: SDhp7lb01-45b016634f16c79e5f1346503fe94984-ct72062
From: <sip:056123456@*.*.*.*;user=phone>;tag=SDhp7lb01-ltm9m107-CC-28
To: <sip:431234567@*.*.*.*;user=phone>
```

Answer (score 1):

The callee is dictated by the request URI so in your example it's `sip:044123456@*.*.*.*:5060;user=phone`.

The [To header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.2) indicate the **logical** recipient. It can be different from the request URI and is not used to determine how a request gets routed.

Based on the information you've provided your provider is right and your PBX developer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The message in your example is an initial INVITE request (no to-tag supplied). This means the Request-URI (in the request line, after INVITE) and the To-URI will have the same value, assuming you don't use (depricated) strict routing.
When using loose routing the Request-URI (and thus the To-URI) of the initial INVITE request will (in general) contain the public address (AOR) of the callee.

When sending in-dialog requests (e.g. a re-INVITE) the Request-URI will contain the remote target address, which is the address the callee returned in the contact header of the INVITE response. The To-URI will not change and thus have the same value as in the initial INVITE request.

More information on Request-URI and To-URI can be found in [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261). See chapter 8.1.1 for initial INVITE requests, 12.2.1 for in-dialog requests (re-INVITEs). This RFC also explains how strict/loose routing affects the Request-URI.

In short: supply the callee's address (AOR) in both the Request-URI and the To-URI. In that case you comply to the RFC and satisfy both your provider and PBX-developer!